# microsoft - what can i do with the free software

Tags: visual-studio, mono

Visual studio is very expensive to buy. This is why I was wondering what can I use for free development of ASP.NET and silverlight applications. If I use the express tools, can I develop comercial applications? How about using Mono and their IDE? What free solution do you prefer?

If anyone has experience with this I would really appreciate your help. This site seems the perfect place for such a question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Express versions for commercial software. The things that are missing from Express are unlikely to be deal-breakers for you. However, should you wish to use a more expensive SKU (pro, premium, or ultimate), take a look at [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8055/can-a-developer-get-volume-discount-for-microsoft-products/8059#8059) on programmers.se which talks about how to pay little or nothing for those skus.

Answer (score 6):

The express editions do not have any restriction in regards to developing commercial applications.

From the [FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Support/Support-faq.aspx):

> - Can I use Express Editions for commercial use?
>
> Yes, there are no licensing restrictions for applications built using Visual Studio Express Editions.

Mono and MonoDevelop are open source, and do not have any restrictions on their usage either.

Comment: Although it should also be pointed out that you can't use plugins in the free express versions - which means things like ReSharper can't be used.

Comment: @slugster Technically, the rule is that you can only use official, sanctioned, plugins. These have to be signed (in a special way?) by Microsoft in order to be usable in the Express editions. Nuget is one of those that are signed as such, however ReSharper isn't.

Comment: Read: It has to be provided by MS and not compete with usages MS reserves for the full Version. TestDriven.NET ran afoul of that.